# how to add a child to existing onetomany relationship in redbeanphp?

Tags: php, mysql, redbean

I am using redbeanphp as my project ORM. I have a table named 'user' witch has one to many relation with 'filter' table.
every one user can have many filter. for adding filter to user i use this code :

```
$user->ownFilterList[] = $filter;
```

this code use work fine when 'ownFilterList' has no filter.
but when I add a filter to existing list it throw this exception.
how can I add a filter to existing list in redbeanphp?

Comment: i can use $filter->user = $user; but i wont to know working from other side.

Comment: thank you for your replay at first ..... answer is "Not", it is really a one to many relationship and only users can multi filter

Comment: it was about my solution in my first comment (set parent of children). but I want to add a new child to parent object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

if we want only add new items to existing **ownList** and removing or modifying **ownList** is not important we can use this method:

```
$user->ownFilterList = array_merg($user->ownFilterList, $newFilters);
```

and then item of $newfilters will be added to Filter table with relation to $user;

we can also use array_push to adding one item to existing list.